# Переход между Фррагментами

Tags: android-studio

Доброго времени суток, сделал переход со страницы Activity на отдельную страницу Fragment. Теперь нужно выполнить переход между Фрагментами по кнопке по аналогии как я сделал это между Activity и Fragment. Пробовал вставлять код как я делал при переходе между Activity и Fragment - не получилось. Прошу помощи студии

Comment: А что не получилось? Добавьте ваш код.

Comment: Я только сейчас понял, что выполнял переход с Activity на Fragment через onNavigationItemSelected. Подскажите другой способ